# Como saber se a data de hoje é sábado ou domingo (final de semana) em PHP?

Tags: php, datetime, data

Quero saber qual é a maneira mais simples possível de se descobrir se a data de hoje é sábado ou domingo em PHP.

Quais são as maneiras possíveis de se fazer isso?

Comment: Defina final de semana :P Até definiu, digo isto porque alguém pode considerar de outra forma.

Comment: Se o cara não souber realmente como saber se é final de semana, aqui no SOPT, ele ganha muitos negativos :p

Comment: Não é tão simples definir final de semana, você deu a definição mais aceita, existem outras, e alguma pode ser mais adequada em cada situação..

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Pra saber se a data corrente é fim de semana:

```
date( 'N' ) > 5       // hora local
gmdate( 'N' ) > 5     // GMT
```

- O parâmetro 'N' retorna os dias de `1` a `7`, sendo 1 Segunda-feira, e 7 Domingo, e funciona do PHP 5.1 em diante.
- O fato de omitir o segundo parâmetro faz com que o date já retorne a data/hora atual, que é o *default*.
- Para fazer operações sem levar em consideração o *timezone* do servidor, basta usar `gmdate()` no lugar do `date()`, em todos os exemplos.

Só de curiosidade, se precisar do 'w' (minusculo!) basta isso:

```
! ( date( 'w' ) % 6 )
```

ou mesmo

```
( date( 'w' ) % 6 ) == 0
```

- o 'w' retorna o dia da semana na faixa de `0` a `6`, sendo `0` Domingo e `6` Sábado.
- O operador `%`, de resto de divisão, faz com que tanto os valores `0` (Domingo) como `6` (sábado) resultem em zero, o que indica final de semana.
- Os `( )` são necessários, pois é PHP, e a ordem de *evaluation* é esquisita.

Se quiser simplificar ainda mais o caso do `'w'`, basta inverter o teste:

```
echo date( 'w' ) % 6 ? 'Não é fim de semana' : 'é fim de semana';
```

Veja no manual todos os parâmetros de `date()`:

> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date.php

Comment: É o jeito "mais simples" até agora.

Comment: Parabéns pela explicação. Percebo que isso falta na maioria das perguntas. Dar a solução sem ensinar não é muito bom.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters depois você fica com preguiça de ler :P

Comment: Fera isso! Eu usava uma gambiarra no minimo dez vezes maior :) Bem explicado

Answer (score 14):

```
if (date('w') == 0 or date('w') == 6) {
    echo "É final de semana ";
}
```

Comment: Agora sim. :) +1

Answer (score 12):

Se você tem o PHP >= 5.1:

```php
function isWeekend($date) {
    return (date('N', strtotime($date)) >= 6);
}
```

senão:

```php
function isWeekend($date) {
    $weekDay = date('w', strtotime($date));
    return ($weekDay == 0 || $weekDay == 6);
}
```

Traduzido de https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802335/checking-if-date-is-weekend-php

Answer (score 12):

Outra forma de saber isso, é pegando o dia por extenso. Como em inglês o sábado (*saturday*) e domingo (*sunday*) iniciam com a letra `S`, basta saber isso.

Veja:

```
if (substr(date('D'), 0, 1) === 'S') {

   echo 'final de semana';

}
```

Se estiver usando o PHP 5.4, pode eliminar o `substr()` e substituir por `[0]`, conhecido como *Function array dereferencing*.

Exemplo:

```
if (date('D')[0] === 'S') {

   echo 'final de semana';

}
```

Comment: Ninguém gostou da sua. Ela funciona, só vai obrigar a Microsoft mudar o nome do próximo Windows por sua causa :P

Comment: @bigown wtf? hahah não entendi a piada xD

Comment: Eu sabia e já me antevi :D http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/30568866#30568866 A piada não é com a resposta, mas é com a MS e os programadores ruins: http://www.extremetech.com/computing/191279-why-is-it-called-windows-10-not-windows-9. E tome um +1

Comment: Olha só, tava faltando o meu +1. Será que tive preconceito com o `substr`? huehuehue

Comment: @WallaceMaxters!11 com certeza xD

Comment: Tem algum problema ou informação errada na resposta? posso corrigir!

Answer (score 9):

Vou dar o meu pitaco na minha própria resposta:

```
in_array(date('w'), [0, 6])
```

No caso, `w` retorna o dia da semana em formato numérico, onde `0`  é domingo e `6`, sábado.

`in_array` fará o trabalho de verificar se o valor do primeiro parâmetro (`$needle`, que traduzindo é "agulha") encontra-se no array que deve ser passado no segundo parâmetro (`$haystack`, que quer dizer "palheiro").

Answer (score 5):

```
<?php
$domingo = mktime(0, 0, 0, 6, 19, 2016); // 19/6/2016
$sabado = mktime(0, 0, 0, 7, 2, 2016); // 2/7/2016
$sexta = mktime(0, 0, 0, 6, 24, 2016); // 24/6/2016

echo "Data 01 : " . (fimDeSemana($domingo) ? "fim de semana" : "dia de semana");
echo "<br/>";
echo "Data 02 : " . (fimDeSemana($sabado) ? "fim de semana" : "dia de semana");
echo "<br/>";
echo "Data 03 : " . (fimDeSemana($sexta) ? "fim de semana" : "dia de semana");


function fimDeSemana($date)
{
    return date("D", $date) === "Sat" or date("D", $date) === "Sun";
}
```

**Saída:**

```
Data 01 : fim de semana
Data 02 : fim de semana
Data 03 : dia de semana
```

Answer (score 1):

Usando a classe [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

```
$str = null;
//$str = '2016-09-24';
$dt = new DateTime($str);
$weekend = ($dt->format('w') % 6) == 0;
var_dump($weekend);
```