# PHP Dias uteis atuais/ Dias faltando

Tags: php, data

Gostaria de saber sobre se tem uma função especifica ou como fazer sobre o dias úteis atuais por exemplo hoje é dia 26 ou seja é 18 dia útil atual do mês e assim vai e conforme troca de mês começa novamente em zero e vai contando conforme o dia útil atual (nunca somando domingo ou sábado).
Exemplo(desse mês):

```
Dia 1(Sexta) = 1 Dia útil.
Dia 2(Sábado) = 0 .
Dia 3(Domingo) = 0 .
Dia 4(Segunda) 2 Dia útil.
```

E também os dias que faltam para terminar o mês por exemplo a partir de hoje faltam 5 dias para terminar o mês.

Comment: Relacionado: [Como saber se a data de hoje é sábado ou domingo (final de semana) em PHP?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136778/91)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Montei uma pequena classe que responde um array com as informações que você precisa.

```
class DiasUteis {

    public static function contarDiasUteis($data, $formato = 'd/m/Y') {

        $dt = DateTime::createFromFormat($formato, $data);
        if ($dt === false) {
            echo "ERRO: A data informada '$data', precisa estar no formato '$formato'.";
            exit;
        }

        $dataUtil = DiasUteis::diaUtil($dt); // a data é útil(true/false)

        $ano = date_format($dt, 'Y');
        $mes = date_format($dt, 'n');
        $ultimo_dia = (integer) date_format($dt, 't');

        $diasUteisNoMes = 0;
        $diasUteisAteData = 0;

        for ($dia = 1; $dia <= $ultimo_dia; $dia++) {
            $dia_contar = DateTime::createFromFormat('j/n/Y', "$dia/$mes/$ano");
            if (DiasUteis::diaUtil($dia_contar)) {
                $diasUteisNoMes++;
                if ($dia_contar <= $dt) {
                    $diasUteisAteData++;
                }
            }
        }
        return [
            'data_util' => $dataUtil
            , 'data_dia_semana' => date_format($dt, 'l')
            , 'dias_uteis_no_mes' => $diasUteisNoMes
            , 'dias_uteis_ate_data' => $diasUteisAteData
            , 'dias_uteis_faltam' => $diasUteisNoMes - $diasUteisAteData
        ];
    }

    private static function diaUtil($dt) {
        if ((date_format($dt, 'N') === '6') || (date_format($dt, 'N') === '7')) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

Como usar:

```
 $resultado = DiasUteis::contarDiasUteis('2016-07-19', 'Y-m-d');
 echo '<pre>';
 var_dump($resultado);
 echo '</pre>';
```

Retorna:

```
array(5) {
  ["data_util"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["data_dia_semana"]=>
  string(7) "Tuesday"
  ["dias_uteis_no_mes"]=>
  int(22)
  ["dias_uteis_ate_data"]=>
  int(13)
  ["dias_uteis_faltam"]=>
  int(9)
}
```

Recomendo uma leitura na [documentação sobre Data e Hora do PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.datetime.php).

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Qualquer dúvida é só perguntar.

Comment: Para retornar um valor especifico neste array como posso fazer ? Por exemplo quero somente o valor dos dias_uteis_no_mes ou só dias_uteis_ate_data

Comment: Como assim, o que gostaria de retornar?

Comment: Não precisa mais já resolvi pra puxar é bem simples eu só coloquei " echo $resultado['dias_uteis_ate_data'];" kkk

Comment: Ok! Fico feliz em ter ajudado!

Comment: Tinha um erro, o correto é: if ((date_format($dt, 'N') === '6') || (date_format($dt, 'N') === '7'))... atualizei a resposta com o código correto.

Answer (score 0):

A função date permite retornar números de acordo com o dia da semana, aí basta você montar uma estrutura de repetição (for/while) que faça o loop e identifique os dias.

Segue um exemplo para saber o dia da semana que eu utilizo.

```
<?
function diasemana($data) {
    $ano =  substr("$data", 0, 4);
    $mes =  substr("$data", 5, -3);
    $dia =  substr("$data", 8, 9);

    $diasemana = date("w", mktime(0,0,0,$mes,$dia,$ano) );

    switch($diasemana) {
        case"0": $diasemana = "Domingo";       break;
        case"1": $diasemana = "Segunda-Feira"; break;
        case"2": $diasemana = "Terça-Feira";   break;
        case"3": $diasemana = "Quarta-Feira";  break;
        case"4": $diasemana = "Quinta-Feira";  break;
        case"5": $diasemana = "Sexta-Feira";   break;
        case"6": $diasemana = "Sábado";        break;
    }

    echo "$diasemana";
}

//Exemplo de uso
diasemana("2007-07-13");
?>
```

Comment: Mas assim eu não iria acumular os dias do mês ? Pois toda semana iria começar zerada de novo não ?