# Como obter a diferença entre datas em dias uteis em MySql?

Tags: mysql

Gostaria de saber se é possível fazer o cálculo da diferença entre 2 datas contabilizando dias úteis.

[Nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/142615/php-dias-uteis-atuais-dias-faltando) até existe uma solução, mas pelo que vi, a verificação é somente para finais de semana, se houver um feriado no meio da semana, o prazo não estará correto.

No momento estou calculando utilizando somente `DATEDIFF`, que retorna a diferença em números de dias corridos.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), '2017-12-20');
```

O resultado que gostaria de obter seria a quantidade de dias entre a data `A` e data `B` excluindo os finais de semana e feriados. Por exemplo, se de uma terça-feira até a terça-feira da semana seguinte tivesse um feriado na quinta-feira, o resultado deveria ser 3 dias úteis (quarta, sexta, segunda).

Comment: Somente os dias úteis?

Comment: @Stormwind acabei me expressando mal, mas atualizei a questão, veja se melhorou a explicação.

Comment: Você vai precisar de uma tabela com os feriados que quer considerar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10330836/how-to-count-date-difference-excluding-weekend-and-holidays-in-mysql

Comment: Para eliminar finais de semana(sábado e domingo), você pode usar a função `DAYOFWEEK` que retorna o dia da semana que sua data se encontra. Ficaria assim: `where DAYOFWEEK(data) not in (1,7)`. Agora para dias úteis é necessário ter uma tabela auxiliar que armazene essas informações.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passei por um problema assim uma vez, resolvemos da seguinte maneira:

Tabela de `dias_uteis`:

```
 CREATE TABLE dias_uteis(
id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    data_util DATE
);
```

Fiz uma `procedure` onde passo o ano e ela insere para mim todas as datas exceto `sábado e domingo`:

```
   --WARNING! ERRORS ENCOUNTERED DURING SQL PARSING!
DROP PROCEDURE

IF EXISTS sp_insere_datas_ano;
    DELIMITER |

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_insere_datas_ano (p_ano INT)

BEGIN
    DECLARE v_date DATE DEFAULT CONCAT (
        p_ano
        ,'-01-01'
        );
    DECLARE v_qtd_dias INT DEFAULT 365;
    DECLARE v_cont INT DEFAULT 1;

    WHILE v_cont < v_qtd_dias DO
        -- AQUI VOCÊ NÃO INSERE SABADOS E DOMINGOS
        IF DAYOFWEEK(v_date) != 1
            AND DAYOFWEEK(v_date) != 7 THEN
            INSERT INTO dias_uteis (data_util) VALUE (v_date);
END

IF ;
    SET v_date = DATE_ADD(v_date, INTERVAL + 1 DAY);
SET v_cont = v_cont + 1;END

WHILE ;END |
    DELIMITER;
        -- CALL sp_insere_datas_ano(2017);
```

Pegamos o calendário do ano e removemos os feriados:

```
DELETE
FROM dias_uteis
WHERE data_util = [data_deletar];
```

Para contar os dias uteis apenas realizar a consulta:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM dias_uteis
WHERE data_util BETWEEN [inicio]
        AND [fim]
```

Um caso extra seriam feriados municipais, que poderíamos resolver da seguinte forma:

```
CREATE TABLE municipios (
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
    ,nome VARCHAR(100)
    );

CREATE TABLE municipio_dia_ignorar (
    id INT (11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
    ,id_dia_util INT (11) DEFAULT NULL
    ,id_municipio INT (11) DEFAULT NULL
    ,PRIMARY KEY (id)
    ,KEY fk_municipio_dia_ignorar_dia_util(id_dia_util)
    ,KEY fk_municipio_dia_ignorar_municipio(id_municipio)
    );
```

Vamos inserir a cidade de **Curitiba**

```
INSERT INTO municipios (nome)
VALUES ('Curitiba');
```

Consideremos que dia `07/09/2017` é feriado nacional e que Curitiba tenha como feriado municipal dia `08/09/2017`, iriamos deletar o dia 7 da tabela de dias_uteis
e inserir o dia 8 na tabela de ignorar:

```
DELETE
FROM dias_uteis
WHERE data_util = '2017-09-07';

INSERT INTO municipio_dia_ignorar (
    id_dia_util
    ,id_municipio
    )
SELECT id
    ,1
FROM dias_uteis
WHERE dias_uteis.data_util = '2017-09-08';
```

Verificamos a quantidade de dias uteis do dia 1 ao 10:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM dias_uteis d
LEFT JOIN municipio_dia_ignorar mi ON mi.id_dia_util = d.id
    AND mi.id_municipio = 1
WHERE d.data_util BETWEEN '2017-09-01'
        AND '2017-09-10'
    AND mi.id IS NULL
```

E o retorno seriam 4 dias:

```
01/09
04/09
05/09
06/09
```

Comment: Creio ser essa a ideia, mas fiquei pensando como resolveria as situações em que os feriados dos municípios são diferentes? Ou seja, feriados que só existem em um determinado município.

Comment: Bela resposta! @Marconi No meu caso, apenas feriados nacionais são importantes. Mas de fato, se for trabalhar com feriados municipais, o trabalho seria grande.

Comment: @Marconi, ai teríamos que pensar em algo mais complexo, como referenciar com uma tabela de municípios, criar uma tabela auxiliar para remover as datas para determinados municípios, por exemplo uma tabela: datas_municipios_ignore, onde colocaria o id da data e o id do municipio, não vejo um jeito mais simples de fazer isso

Comment: @arllondias eu já acho sua resposta sensacional, se incluir com feriados municipais vai ficar ainda melhor. Já deixei o meu +1!

Comment: @celsomtrindade bom que os nacionais já ajudam, de fato está é a resposta.

Comment: @Marconi, muito obrigado pelo feedback ;)

Comment: editei a resposta implementando a ideia de feriados municipais. @Marconi

Answer (score 1):

Pode ser algo assim:

```
SELECT *
FROM minhatabela
WHERE date BETWEEN @inicio AND @fim
AND WEEKDAY(date) < 5
```

Isso, claro, não resolve a questão dos feriados.

Answer (score 1):

Aproveitando a ideia do amigo, incrementei os feriados nacionais no próprio procedimento.

Base de feriados: https://www.anbima.com.br/feriados/arqs/feriados_nacionais.xls

Coloquei um evento para chamar uma vez por ano e já resolve para mim.

No caso de municipais realmente não vejo uma forma sem ser com um job externo.

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `stpBusinessDay`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE `stpBusinessDay`(_year YEAR)
BEGIN

    DECLARE _i INT DEFAULT 1;
    DECLARE _limit INT DEFAULT 365;
    DECLARE _dt DATE DEFAULT CONCAT (_year,'-01-01');

    TRUNCATE TABLE tbBusinessDay;
    
    WHILE _i < _limit DO
        IF DAYOFWEEK(_dt) NOT IN(1,7) THEN
            INSERT INTO `tbBusinessDay` VALUE (_dt);
        END IF ;
        SET _dt = DATE_ADD(_dt, INTERVAL + 1 DAY);
        SET _i = _i + 1;
    END WHILE;

    WITH dayOff AS (
        SELECT CONCAT (_year,'-01-01') AS dt -- Confraternização Universal
        UNION
        SELECT CONCAT (_year,'-02-24') AS dt -- Carnaval
        UNION
        SELECT CONCAT (_year,'-02-25') AS dt -- Carnaval
        UNION
        SELECT CONCAT (_year,'-04-10') AS dt -- Paixão de Cristo
        UNION
        SELECT CONCAT (_year,'-04-21') AS dt -- Tiradentes
        UNION
        SELECT CONCAT (_year,'-05-01') AS dt -- Dia do Trabalho
        UNION
        SELECT CONCAT (_year,'-06-11') AS dt -- Corpus Christi
        UNION
        SELECT CONCAT (_year,'-09-07') AS dt -- Independência do Brasil
        UNION
        SELECT CONCAT (_year,'-10-12') AS dt -- Nossa Sr.a Aparecida - Padroeira do Brasil
        UNION
        SELECT CONCAT (_year,'-11-02') AS dt -- Finados
        UNION
        SELECT CONCAT (_year,'-11-15') AS dt -- Proclamação da República
        UNION   
        SELECT CONCAT (_year,'-12-25') AS dt -- Natal
    )
    DELETE A FROM `tbBusinessDay` A
    INNER JOIN dayOff B ON (A.dt = B.dt);
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```