# Como saber se um determinado dia é final de semana?

Tags: php, data

Como saber se um dia informado, do mês atual, caiu no final de semana? Por exemplo:

```
echo isWeekend(24) // True
echo isWeekend(26) // False
```

No tópico relacionado abaixo, eu consigo saber o dia de hoje através do método `date`:

```
date('w')
```

Porém não há uma função no método `date` para algo parecido com o que quero.

Pretendo obter uma lista com o total dos dias do mês com `cal_days_in_month` e verificar dia por dia, caso seja um final de semana, receberá tratamento diferenciado.

Relacionada: [Como saber se a data de hoje é sábado ou domingo (final de semana) em PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/136778/como-saber-se-a-data-de-hoje-%C3%A9-s%C3%A1bado-ou-domingo-final-de-semana-em-php)

Comment: Sabendo somente o dia não dá pra dizer se ele caiu no final de semana, tem coisa faltando ai.

Comment: Complementei, pode ser o mês atual. @rray

Comment: @Bacco, pretendo obter uma lista com o total dos dias do mês, [`cal_days_in_month`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.cal-days-in-month.php) e verificar dia por dia, caso seja um final de semana, receberá tratamento diferenciado.

Comment: Respondi dando uma idéia geral, basta aplicar o mktime no seu loop. Mas quando for assim, ponha o problema completo na pergunta, pq pode ter maneiras melhores de se fazer. Sempre faça seus posts da maneira mais completa possível. Isso ajuda a gente a te ajudar. As respostas são feitas em cima do que é perguntado.

Comment: Relevante: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/70473/132 - Dê uma olhada na minha resposta, pois uma das coisas que ela aborda é a determinação do dia da semana.

Comment: @Bacco foi distração minha, complementei a pergunta com o comentário.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Para criar uma data, você tem as funções `mktime` e `gmmktime`:

```
mktime (
  [ int $hora [, int $minuto [, int $segundo[
  , int $mes [, int $dia [, int $ano [, int $is_dst ]]]]]]]
)
```

Sabendo disto, basta usar o que está na pergunta mencionada:

```
$dataescolhida = mktime ( 0, 0, 0, 5, 31, 2016 );

if( date( 'N', $dataescolhida ) > 5 ) { ...
```

Versão com parâmetro `w`:

```
if( ( date( 'w', $dataescolhida ) % 6 ) == 0 ) { ...
```

O código acima diz se 31/05/2016 caiu num fim de semana.

Cuidado com a ordem dos parâmetros, pois como PHP não tem critério, o mês vem antes do dia.

Mais detalhes em:

> https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/136780/70

Answer (score 6):

O `mktime` resolve este problema, o @Bacco já disse o essencial, deixo aqui apenas mais um exemplo:

```
function finalDeSemana($aData) {
   $dia = substr($aData, 0, 2);
   $mes = substr($aData, 3, 2);
   $ano = substr($aData, 6, 4);
   $date = date('w', mktime(0, 0, 0, $mes, $dia, $ano));

   if ($date == 6): 
      echo 'Sábado' . '<br>';
   elseif ($date == 0): 
      echo 'Domingo' . '<br>';
   else:
      echo 'Não é final de semana' . '<br>';
   endif;
}

finalDeSemana('26/07/2016');
finalDeSemana('27/07/2016');
finalDeSemana('28/07/2016');
finalDeSemana('29/07/2016');
finalDeSemana('30/07/2016');
finalDeSemana('31/07/2016');
```

**Saída:**

```
Não é final de semana
Não é final de semana
Não é final de semana
Não é final de semana
Sábado
Domingo
```

Answer (score 5):

Desconheço algum método nativo que retorne se é final de semana ou não, porém, poderia ser implementando através de uma simples função:

```
function isWeekend($dia) {
    $mes = date('n');
    $ano = date('Y');
    $dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('j/n/Y', "$dia/$mes/$ano");
    if ((date_format($dt, 'N') === '6') || (date_format($dt, 'N') === '7')) {
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Uso:

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump(isWeekend(24));
echo '</pre>';

echo '<pre>';
var_dump(isWeekend(25));
echo '</pre>';

echo '<pre>';
var_dump(isWeekend(26));
echo '</pre>';
```

Resultado para código rodado hoje (26/07/2016):

```
bool(true) // para dia 24/07/2016 
bool(false) // para dia 25/07/2016 
bool(false)// para dia 26/07/2016
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer assim também.

```
<?php

function checkDayFDS($day){

  $nameDay = date("D", strtotime($day));
  $fds     = "Hoje não é final de semana<hr>";  

  if ($nameDay == "Sat" || $nameDay == "Sun"){
    $fds = "Oba, hoje é final de semana<hr>";
  }

  return $fds;
}


echo checkDayFDS("2017-08-18");// Sexta 
echo checkDayFDS("2017-08-19");// Sabado
echo checkDayFDS("2017-08-20");// Domingo
echo checkDayFDS("2017-08-21");// Segunda
?>
```

Comment: Da uma olhada nesse exemplo: http://www.wsasystens.xyz/fds.php?dia=2017-08-19