# Como saber quantos domingos tem o os meses do ano php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Digamos que o ano seja: `2016`
 Preciso saber quantos domingos tem o os meses do ano e gravar e resultado em variável php.
 Motivo:
 Preciso passar uma condição,exemplo:

```
if ($dom_mes == 4 )
{     
    //CONDIÇÃO A     
} 
elseif ($dom_mes == 5 )
{
    //CONDIÇÃO B    
}
else
{
    //NADA A FAZER    
}
```

Comment: pode começar por aqui http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136778/4793

Comment: Reverti sua edição, pois ela invalida as respostas existentes. Se tem nova dúvida, faça em separado.

Comment: Ok,@Bacco , Obrigado.

Comment: @otaciojb lembre-se de por todos os detalhes na nova pergunta, para evitar ter que modificar depois. Quando ainda está sem resposta, ainda dá (correndo o risco de prejudicar alguém que está desenvolvendo algo pra postar). Quando são pequenos detalhes, tudo bem, mas é que neste caso, ia modificar o essencial da pergunta. Complementos são sempre bem-vindos, desde que não mudem o principal.

Comment: @Bacco Blza,Aobrigado. Veja nova pergunta,creio que ficou bem clara: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/160477/passar-resultados-de-um-array-em-condi%C3%A7%C3%B5es-else-if

Comment: @otaciojb acho que dá pra explicar um pouco melhor o resultado que quer obter. Lembre-se que pode ser que o pessoal entre lá, e não tenha visto esta postagem aqui. Se quiser, pode por um link naquela indicando o código desta aqui que está usando como referência.

Comment: Respondi sua outra pergunta @otaciojb . Dá uma olhada se ficou legal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pode pegar mês por mês. Modifiquei o exemplo para fazer um loop:

```
<?php
$array = [];
$ano = 2016;


for($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++){
    $data = $ano . '-' . $i. '-01';

    $inicio = new DateTime($data);
    $fim = new DateTime($inicio->format('Y-m-t'));
    $dias = $inicio->diff($fim, true)->days;

    $array[$i] = intval($dias / 7) + ($inicio->format('N') + $dias % 7 >= 7);
}
?>
<pre>
<?=print_r($array) ?>
</pre>
```

Comment: Rodei e me voltou 55, estou tentando ver o que pode estar errado:

Comment: Editei o código. Vê se te atende

Comment: Array
(
    [1] => 5
    [2] => 4
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 4
    [5] => 5
    [6] => 4
    [7] => 5
    [8] => 4
    [9] => 4
    [10] => 5
    [11] => 4
    [12] => 4
)
1 , Perfeito, Obrigado !

Comment: Retorna em 0.1 milisegundos

Answer (score 6):

Segue uma solução alternativa:

```
function domingosNoMes( $mes, $ano ) {
    $t = gmmktime( 0, 0, 0, $mes, 1, $ano );
    $ult = date( 't', $t );
    $sem  = date( 'w', $t );
    return floor( ( $ult - 1 ) / 7 ) + ( $sem == 0 || $sem > ( 35 - $ult ) );
}
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/ueyvPj)**.

É parecida com a técnica matemática do Hugo Leonardo, que dispensa uso de *loops*, só muda a parte de usar funções nativas diretamente, sem objetos.

Se quiser, dá para simplificar mais ainda usando `N` no lugar do `w` no `date`, caso não precise compatibilidade com versões mais velhas do PHP, facilitando a remoção do `||` da expressão, com um pequeno ajuste.

Vale lembrar que, se estiver usando um PHP 32 bits, usar *timestamps* só funciona até 2038. Agora, se alguém ainda estiver usando coisas em 32 bits em pleno 2038, com certeza tem problemas bem mais sérios que *timestamp* :D

Comment: Retorna em 0.054 milisegundos

Answer (score 2):

Mais um

```
<?php

$week_day = 1; // The desired week day (sunday: 1, monday:2 .... saturday: 0)
$year = '2016'; // Year, 4 digits

$rs = array();
$month = 1;
while ($month <= 12) {
    $day = 1;
    $date = new DateTime($year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day);
    $day_last = $date->format('t');
    $i = 1;
    while ($day <= $day_last) {
        $date->add(new DateInterval('P'.$i.'D'));
        //$date->add(date_interval_create_from_date_string($i.' days'));
        $day_week = $date->format('w');
        if ($day_week == $week_day) {
            $rs[$month][] = $day;
            $i = 7;
        }
        $day += $i;
    }
    $month++;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($rs);
echo '</pre>';
```

Mantém uma única instância de `DateTime()` para cada mês ao invés de criar uma instância para cada dia de cada mês.

Não percorre todos os dias de todos o meses.

Ao identificar o primeiro “domingo”, o contador pula de 7 em 7, trazendo um ganho considerável de perfomance do que verificar dia por dia. Ou seja, ao invés de fazer 365/366 iterações, perfaz somente algo em torno de 52.

A rotina é reutilizável. Apenas modifique o código do dia da semana e o ano para obter resultados para outros dias ou anos.

```
1: Domingo
2: Segunda
3: Terça
4: Quarta
5: Quinta
6: Sexta
0: Sábado
```

O retorno é um array multidimensional. Para o ano 2016, esse é o resultado:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 10
            [2] => 17
            [3] => 24
            [4] => 31
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7
            [1] => 14
            [2] => 21
            [3] => 28
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6
            [1] => 13
            [2] => 20
            [3] => 27
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 10
            [2] => 17
            [3] => 24
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 8
            [2] => 15
            [3] => 22
            [4] => 29
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 12
            [2] => 19
            [3] => 26
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 10
            [2] => 17
            [3] => 24
            [4] => 31
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7
            [1] => 14
            [2] => 21
            [3] => 28
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 11
            [2] => 18
            [3] => 25
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 9
            [2] => 16
            [3] => 23
            [4] => 30
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6
            [1] => 13
            [2] => 20
            [3] => 27
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 11
            [2] => 18
            [3] => 25
        )

)
```

Basta iterar o resultado para extrair o que precisa.

Preferi omitir essa parte pois iterar `array()` é algo muito básico.

Outro ponto relevante é que a rotina ainda funcionará mesmo depois do ano 2038.

Claro que em 2038 será raro ou nulo alguém usando sistemas 32 bits. A preocupação é com a época atual. Ainda muitos usam sistemas 32 bits atualmente e podem querer fazer operações com datas após 2038 sob ambientes esses ambientes, o que pode retornar resultados errôneos.

Mais um detalhe, independente da solução que escolher, salve o resultado num arquivo estático ou mesmo num banco de dados porque se precisar executar novamente não precisa rodar tudo de novo. Se executou uma vez, a segunda vez em diante é redundante pois trará sempre o mesmo resultado. Isso é questão de performance e otimização. Faça como achar melhor.

## Versão otimizada

Essa nova versão otimizada executa 0.21 milisegundos. A anterior executa em 0.245 milisegundos. Também consome menos memória, economizando cerca de 458 bytes em relação a original

Segue a mesma lógica da original com a diferença de que agora é criada apenas uma instância de `Datetime()`.

O que mata um pouco a performance é ter que invocar `$date->format('m')` e `$date->format('d')` para obter o mês e o dia. Que são opcionais pois a pergunta não pede isso. Mas preferi mostrar um resultado mais detalhado informando quais os dias onde foram encontrados o dia da semana, no caso o domingo.

O limite de repetições é o número total de dias do ano. O total é 366 para ano bissexto e 365 para ano não bissexto.

Ao encontrar o primeiro "domingo", os incrementos são de 7 em 7 dias, evitando assim que o laço itere 365 ou 366 vezes. Nesse esquema, temos apenas 54 iterações.

```
$week_day = 0; // The desired week day (sunday: 1, monday:2 .... saturday: 0)
$year = '2016'; // Year, 4 digits

$rs = array();
$days = (((($year % 4) == 0) && ((($year % 100) != 0) || (($year %400) == 0))))? 366: 365;
$date = new DateTime(($year - 1).'-12-31');
$day = 1;
$i = 1;
while ($day <= $days) {
    $date->add(new DateInterval('P'.$i.'D'));
    //$date->add(date_interval_create_from_date_string($i.' days'));
    $day_week = (int)$date->format('w');
    if ($day_week == $week_day) {
        $rs[(int)$date->format('m')][] = (int)$date->format('d');
        $i = 7;
    }
    $day += $i;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($rs);
echo '</pre>';
```

Fiz também uma mudança em ambas as versões no seguinte trecho

```
    $date->add(new DateInterval('P'.$i.'D'));
    //$date->add(date_interval_create_from_date_string($i.' days'));
```

A versão original foi construída com PHP rodando sob Android. Nesse PHP não tem a classe `DateInterval()` mesmo sendo a versão 7. Por isso usei `date_interval_create_from_date_string()`.

Agora fiz usando um Pc Windows e pude otimizar mais trocando de volta para `new DateInterval()` pois `date_interval_create_from_date_string()` é um alias do mesmo. Funções de alias (atalho), são sempre mais "lentas".