# Passar resultados de um array em condições else if

Tags: php, array

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
<?php
$array = [];
$ano = 2016;


for($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++){
    $data = $ano . '-' . $i. '-01';

    $inicio = new DateTime($data);
    $fim = new DateTime($inicio->format('Y-m-t'));
    $dias = $inicio->diff($fim, true)->days;

    $array[$i] = intval($dias / 7) + ($inicio->format('N') + $dias % 7 >= 7);

}


     $janeiro  = $array[1];
     $fevereiro= $array[2];
     $marco    = $array[3];
     $abril    = $array[4];
     $maio     = $array[5];
     $junho    = $array[6];
     $julho    = $array[7];
     $agosto   = $array[8];
     $setembro = $array[9];
     $outubro  = $array[10];
     $novembro = $array[11];
     $dezembro = $array[12];



if      ($janeiro == 4){

    //CONDIÇÃO 01

}elseif ($janeiro == 5){

    //CONDINÇÃO 02

}else{


}


if      ($fevereiro == 4){

    //CONDIÇÃO 01

}elseif ($fevereiro == 5){

    //CONDINÇÃO 02

}else{


}

if      ($marco == 4){

    //CONDIÇÃO 01

}elseif ($marco == 5){

    //CONDINÇÃO 02

}else{


}

if      ($abril == 4){

    //CONDIÇÃO 01

}elseif ($abril == 5){

    //CONDINÇÃO 02

}else{


}

if      ($maio == 4){

    //CONDIÇÃO 01

}elseif ($maio == 5){

    //CONDINÇÃO 02

}else{


}

if      ($junho == 4){

    //CONDIÇÃO 01

}elseif ($junho == 5){

    //CONDINÇÃO 02

}else{


}

if      ($julho == 4){

    //CONDIÇÃO 01

}elseif ($julho == 5){

    //CONDINÇÃO 02

}else{


}

if      ($agosto == 4){

    //CONDIÇÃO 01

}elseif ($agosto == 5){

    //CONDINÇÃO 02

}else{


}


if      ($setembro == 4){

    //CONDIÇÃO 01

}elseif ($setembro == 5){

    //CONDINÇÃO 02

}else{


}

if      ($outubro == 4){

    //CONDIÇÃO 01

}elseif ($outubro == 5){

    //CONDINÇÃO 02

}else{


}

if      ($novembro == 4){

    //CONDIÇÃO 01

}elseif ($novembro == 5){

    //CONDINÇÃO 02

}else{


}

if      ($dezembro == 4){

    //CONDIÇÃO 01

}elseif ($dezembro == 5){

    //CONDINÇÃO 02

}else{


}

?>
```

Qual seria a forma mais simples e limpa de fazer as condiçoes acima ?

Comment: é sempre a mesma condição? No caso você tem duas condições somente? "CONDIÇÃO 01" E "CONDIÇÃO 02"?

Comment: @MarllonNasser sim

Comment: Não entendo esses caras,a pergunta em meu ver foi clara,teve uma boa resposta e estão pedindo para fecha-la, aff's vai entender ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Amigo, coloquei a condição diretamente dentro do primeiro loop:

```
$meses = [1 => 'jan', 2 => 'fev', 3 => 'mar', 4 => 'abr', 5 => 'mai', 6 => 'jun', 7 => 'jul', 8 =>'ago', 9 => 'set', 10 => 'out', 11 => 'nov', 12 => 'dez'];
$ano = 2016;

for($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++){
    $data = $ano . '-' . $i. '-01';

    $inicio = new DateTime($data);
    $fim = new DateTime($inicio->format('Y-m-t'));
    $dias = $inicio->diff($fim, true)->days;

    $res = intval($dias / 7) + ($inicio->format('N') + $dias % 7 >= 7);
    if($res == 4){
        echo $meses[$i] . " tem " . $res . " está na condição 1<br />";
    }elseif($res == 5){
        echo $meses[$i] . " tem " . $res . " está na condição 2<br />";
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfeito,era isso mesmo,Obrigado !

Answer (score 3):

Acho que a grande questão é saber realmente se você precisa de tais condições.... validar sempre o mesmo dessa forma com as mesmas condições aparenta uma lógica errada.. Mas enfim, eu faria da seguinte forma:

```
if (umNomeCoerenteParaSuaFuncao(4)) {
   //CONDIÇÃO 01
} elseif (umNomeCoerenteParaSuaFuncao(5)) {
   //CONDIÇÃO 02
}


function umNomeCoerenteParaSuaFuncao($valorBuscado) {
   return $janeiro == $valorBuscado || $fevereiro == $valorBuscado || $marco == $valorBuscado || $abril == $valorBuscado || $maio == $valorBuscado || $junho == $valorBuscado || $julho == $valorBuscado || $agosto == $valorBuscado || $setembro == $valorBuscado || $outubro == $valorBuscado || $novembro == $valorBuscado || $dezembro == $valorBuscado;
}
```

Apesar de já diminuir e muito as linhas de código, eu acho que você deveria repensar na necessidade de tamanhas validações repetidas.

**EDIT:**

Outra forma de se alcançar uma validação dessa é através do [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.in-array.php)

```
if (in_array(4, $array)) {
   //CONDIÇÃO 01
} elseif (in_array(5, $array)) {
   //CONDIÇÃO 02
}
```