# Dia da semana pela variavel php

Tags: php, data

Estou querendo pegar a data por extenso. O código abaixo está pegando certo, porém, a data atual do computador.

Gostaria que fosse conforme eu colocar a data vindo de uma variável tipo 01/09/2017.

```
<?php
$meses = array (1 => "Janeiro", 2 => "Fevereiro", 3 => "Março", 4 => "Abril", 5 => "Maio", 6 => "Junho", 7 => "Julho", 8 => "Agosto", 9 => "Setembro", 10 => "Outubro", 11 => "Novembro", 12 => "Dezembro");
$diasdasemana = array (1 => "Segunda-Feira",2 => "Terça-Feira",3 => "Quarta-Feira",4 => "Quinta-Feira",5 => "Sexta-Feira",6 => "Sábado",0 => "Domingo");
 $hoje = getdate();
 $dia = $hoje["mday"];
 $mes = $hoje["mon"];
 $nomemes = $meses[$mes];
 $ano = $hoje["year"];
 $diadasemana = $hoje["wday"];
 $nomediadasemana = $diasdasemana[$diadasemana];
 echo "$nomediadasemana, $dia de $nomemes de $ano"; ?>
```

Comment: Você que fez o código? Se sim, sabe o que a função `getdate` faz?

Comment: Nao Anderson peguei em outro fórum

Comment: Então comece estudando a função [`getdate`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.getdate.php) e já leia sobre a função [`strtotime`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strtotime.php).

Comment: Mesmo sem resposta eu agradeço muito !

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como saber se a data de hoje é sábado ou domingo (final de semana) em PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/136778/como-saber-se-a-data-de-hoje-%c3%a9-s%c3%a1bado-ou-domingo-final-de-semana-em-php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$meses = array (1 => "Janeiro", 2 => "Fevereiro", 3 => "Março", 4 => "Abril", 5 => "Maio", 6 => "Junho", 7 => "Julho", 8 => "Agosto", 9 => "Setembro", 10 => "Outubro", 11 => "Novembro", 12 => "Dezembro");
$diasdasemana = array (1 => "Segunda-Feira",2 => "Terça-Feira",3 => "Quarta-Feira",4 => "Quinta-Feira",5 => "Sexta-Feira",6 => "Sábado",0 => "Domingo");

$variavel = "01/09/2017";
$variavel = str_replace('/','-',$variavel);

$hoje = getdate(strtotime($variavel));

$dia = $hoje["mday"];
$mes = $hoje["mon"];
$nomemes = $meses[$mes];
$ano = $hoje["year"];
$diadasemana = $hoje["wday"];
$nomediadasemana = $diasdasemana[$diadasemana];

echo "$nomediadasemana, $dia de $nomemes de $ano";
```

Comment: Perfeito meu nobre !

Comment: Obg! Fiz uma edição tirando `variavel_convertida` e deixando tudo apenas `variavel`.

Comment: É interessante notar que exatamente o mesmo código da pergunta poderia ser utilizado apenas `getdate(strtotime($data))`. Veja um exemplo: https://ideone.com/YLRK4i

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss É verdade. Mas veja que o formato da data que ele queria é com /.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Realmente o código ficou bem melhor agora. Vc estava certo, era só trocar a variável $hoje.

Answer (score 6):

Como alternativa, você pode utilizar a função `strftime`, desde que o *locale* esteja devidamente configurado. Veja um exemplo:

```
<?php

if (setlocale(LC_TIME, 'pt')) {
    echo strftime("%A, %e de %B de %Y", strtotime("01-09-2017")), PHP_EOL;
}
```

> Como comentado, inclusive na outra resposta, existe diferença no PHP entre utilizar `-` e `/` como separador. Se usar `-`, o PHP considerará o formato `dd-mm-YYYY`, mas se usar `/` o PHP considerará `mm/dd/YYYY`. Vide [documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php), terceira nota.

Primeiro, é configurado o *locale* para `pt`. Se alterado com sucesso, exibe a data representada por `strtotime("01-09-2017")` no formato `%A, %e de %B de %Y`, onde:

- `%A` retorna o dia da semana por extenso;
- `%e` retorna o dia em numeral, sem zeros à esquerda;
- `%B` retorna o nome do mês por extenso, e
- `%Y` retorna o ano com quatro dígitos.

A saída seria:

```
sexta-feira,  1 de setembro de 2017
```